# Overhead of delegate definition inside of another method

Tags: c#, performance, anonymous-function

I'm curious to understand what's happening behind the scenes in a situation like this:

```
public static void OuterMethod() {
    // some random code
    var a = 42;
    var b = "meaning of life";        

    Func<string, object> factory = (aString) {
        // do something with a and b
        return "Hello World";
    };

    // some more random code
    factory("My string");
}
```

I'm particularly interested in cases where `OuterMethod` is called very often. In my case it's the MVC request pipeline where `OuterMethod` is called once for each request.

Am I incurring a lot overhead by having to build `factory` each time the method is called? I could easily move the Func outside of `OuterMethod` into its own static method however in my actual scenario because it is defined inside I have access to a lot of variables I need to do my calculation that I would otherwise need to include in the signature of a method defined outside. Maybe this is just a micro optimization but I would like to better understand how the compiler treats these kinds of statements.

Comment: Servy's answer is correct you will be creating a new reference to the delegate for each time OuterMethod is called.  From a design prespective though, this would likely violate the single reponsibility principle.  OuterMethod is responsible for building objects (or performing a calculation) AND whatever OuterMethod's real job is.  So having the factory/calculation in its own method would be preferable.  Of course, if you are using OuterMethod just to create a State Environment for the delegate then that's OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual lambda is going to result in a new named method (you just don't know what that name is) being created at compile time (the exact semantics will vary based on some of the specifics).

The only work being done on each invocation of the method is the creation of a new delegate object that has its own pointer to the same named method.  If constructing that one object instance is *really* too much for you (hint: its not) then you could save that work by extracting the delegate out of the method.

Comment: Thanks! Always appreciate your insight. I had a feeling that it would be taken care of for me in some way at compile time but just wanted to be sure :)